# Locating zeros of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

Given polynomial with real coefficients 
$$p(x) = x^n + a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n,$$
is there some method for deciding if it has zeros in some interval, for example $(0,1)$? There exist methods for either positive or negative zeros but I am interested for zeros in a specific interval.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) allows you to do that.

Small example:

$$p(x)=x^2-1/4$$

We compute $$p'(x)=2x$$

and the opposite of the remainder of the division of $p$ by $p'$ which is, up to a positive constant factor, $$1$$

Now we evaluate those three $(p(x),p'(x),1)$ at $x=0$ to get $(-1/4, 0, 1)$ and at $x=1$ to get $(3/4,2,1)$. The first triple has $1$ change of sign, and the second has $0$ changes of sign. Therefore, there are $1-0=1$ zero of $p$ inside $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

If the polynomial
$$
(1+x)^np(\frac1{1+x})
$$
has only positive coefficients, then you know that there are no roots in the interval $(0,1)$ by the Descartes rule of signs. If there is one sign change in the coefficient sequence, then there  is exactly one root in this interval by the same rule.

Also check the Budan-Fourier theorem, if the number of sign changes in the coefficient sequence of $p(a+x)$ and $p(b+x)$ differs by zero or one, then there are zero or exactly one solutions in $[a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

Use rolle's theorem. Integrate the polynomial. If the values of the integral at extreme values are equal then there exists a root in the interval.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem right.  For $f(x) = x - 1/4$ this prescription seems to suggest examining $g(x) = x^2/2 - x/4$, $g(0) = 0$, and $g(1) = 1/4$, then concluding there is no zero in $f$ at $1/4$ because $g(0) \neq g(1)$.  Is this the process you intended?

Comment: @EricTowers This seems to be the process that was intended, but it is a sufficient and not necessary condition. It only covers a negligible set of cases, so it is not really a productive approach in general.